# Inherited EditorServerCommandAction double posts ReturnMessage

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-9.3, .net, arcgis-web-adf

I have a bunch of inherited `EditorServerCommandActions` in my WebADF solution and whenever I use the `ReturnMessage` inside `EditorServerAction()` it generates two javascript popups at the client side.

Is this a common know error or am I simply missing something?

```
public class CustomCommandAction : EditorServerCommandAction
{
    protected override void EditorServerAction()
    {
        ReturnMessage("Foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of ArcGIS?

Comment: It's runing at v. 9.3.1

Answer (score 2):

I know this might sound obvious, but is something calling that routine twice? If you set a break point at ReturnMessage is it hit twice? If so, you could dig into where it is coming from. Perhaps there is more than one instance of the CustomCommandAction somehow.

Comment: I took a peek at EditorServerCommandAction in Reflector, and the ServerAction(ToolbarItemInfo) method calls ReturnMessage.